# Libgdx scene2d actor appear and fade out randomly

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

So I have a sceneu2.ui table like this:

```
+--------------------------------------+
|+---------+ +------------+ +---------+|
|| Table 1 | | ScrollPane | | Table 2 ||
|+---------+ +------------+ +---------+|
+--------------------------------------+
|                             My Actor |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Inside the `scrollpane` is another `table`. The enclosure is also a `table`. `Table 1`, `Table 2` and `table` inside `scrollpane` have same number of row.

`My Actor` is simple image button actor that also support mouseover.

The problem is that, `My Actor` doesn't appear at first (but it's boundary exists -- checked by table debug line) but when I scroll something in `scrollpane` (with mouse) it appear for 2 seconds, and then begin to fade away. (the expected result should be it appear all the time)

What am I doing wrong?

---

The `My Actor` class:

```
public class GameButton extends Actor {
    public static abstract class Listener {
        public abstract void onClick();
    }

    final Texture[] current;
    final Listener listener;
    boolean disabled;
    int state = 0;

    public GameButton(Texture[] current, final Listener listener) {
        this.current = current;
        setWidth(current[0].getWidth());
        setHeight(current[0].getHeight());

        this.listener = listener;
        disabled = false;

        this.addListener(new InputListener() {
            boolean just_up = false;

            @Override
            public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                state = 2;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                state = 0;
                if (hit(x, y, false) != null) {
                    just_up = true;
                    state = 1;
                    if (listener != null && !disabled)
                        listener.onClick();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void enter (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
                if (state == 0)
                    state = 1;
            }

            @Override
            public void exit (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor toActor) {
                if (!just_up)
                    state = 0;
                just_up = false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void setDisabled(boolean disabled) {
        this.disabled = disabled;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float _) {
        super.draw(batch, _);
        batch.draw(current[disabled ? 0 : state], getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

The code which is used to add this to table:

```
    btnBack = new GameButton(Assets.btnBack, 0, 0, new GameButton.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            /* removed */
        }
    });
    add(btnBack).colspan(3).right().bottom().height(128);
```

Comment: It looks like you are reinventing a libgdx button. Any reason you aren't using it?

Comment: Because its documentation sucks. I thought it doesn't support mouseover state at first, but when I actually try to use it, my editor autocomplete told me that it actually has `over` field that I could set the mouseover drawable. But this still don't answer why isn't this working.

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem??

Answer (score 5):

I realize this question is 2 years old, but I also had this problem so thought I would post my solution. For me it was simply a case of setting the scroll bar fade to false, using

```
ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();
scroll.setFadeScrollBars(false);
```

Answer (score 4):

add to the draw method in the actor setColor(1,1,1,1)

```
@Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float _) {
        batch.setColor(1,1,1,1);
        super.draw(batch, _);
        batch.draw(current[disabled ? 0 : state], getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't test whether your answer is right or wrong because I have already changed to other workaround (and I don't remember what). And that project was done months ago.

Still, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Yep dont worry, i had the same issue and i solved the way i post =)

Answer (score 0):

The default "blank" skin/behavior for the ScrollPane does some fading in and out. It isn't clear to me why, but it can cause other things on the screen to fade as well. I was having this same issue with background images. I suspect that if you define your own skin for ScrollPane, you'll see your button appear.